# C# form SQL selection drop down list like Windows ODBC

Tags: c#

I have a question about selecting a data source for my dropdown list in a form.
I've found plenty of info on selecting an sql as the source for the dropdown.

But what I need is a dropdown that shows a list of the available sql servers on the network like Windows odbc (datasources) does.

Any insight?

Comment: It is a good idea to include code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: I would, and I usually do.  But in this case I have nothing to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Retrieve the enumerator instance and then the data.
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance =
  SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
```

You can use this as data source for your dropdown.

Comment: Do you need more help? If not, and the answer was good to you, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hey sorry.  Yeah that helped right away!  That's exactly what was needed. Just couldn't mark it because of the time.  It's marked now!